# Change jQuery UI time slider intervals to hour, and add ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was looking for a simple jQuery time slider to integrate with my google maps v3 webmap, and I found this codes that are working perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .ui-slider-range {
            background: rgb(255, 130, 37);
        }
    </style>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            function pad(num, size) {
                var s = num + "";
                while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
                return s;
            }
            var formatSecs = function (totalsecs) {
                var hour = parseInt(totalsecs / 3600, 10) % 24;
                var min = parseInt(totalsecs / 60, 10) % 60;
                var secs = totalsecs % 60;

                return pad(hour, 2) + ":" + pad(min, 2) + ":" + pad(secs, 2);
            };

            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 86400,
                values: [7200, 72000],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var min = ui.values[0];
                    var max = ui.values[1];

                    $("#amount").val(formatSecs(min) + " - " + formatSecs(max));
                }
            });

            $("#amount").val(formatSecs($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)) + " - " + formatSecs($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)));

        });
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <label for="amount">Time range:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>

    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

But the only problem is that it the toggle moves in the interval of seconds. I just want it to move by hours instead, so it is not as smooth, or if the transition can't be changed, I want to add ticks to the bottom like in the example shown by user "pliablepixels" in this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/range-slider-with-ticks/29203/3) so at least the user can gauge where is next hour they can pull the slider to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `step` property of the slider like so:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 86400,
    values: [7200, 72000],
    step: 3600,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var min = ui.values[0];
        var max = ui.values[1];

        $("#amount").val(formatSecs(min) + " - " + formatSecs(max));
    }
});
```

Notice the `step: 3600,`, this will increment the time by steps of 1 hour.

`3600` (number of secs in an hour) has been used since your whole range is in terms of seconds as well.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzbbc0d/)

You can also add the following code to smooth out the movement when changing range:

```
$(".ui-slider-range, .ui-slider-handle").css("transition", "all 0.4s");
```

[Here is the **updated** code](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzbbc0d/1/)

Comment: really clever.
Thank you!